# How do I use an older version of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The latest version (0.5.0) comes with constant crashes, so I wish to go back to the previous version (0.3.0), which actually worked.

How can I achieve this on a Windows machine? First, I embarrassingly don't know where to actually download the old version, and second, I don't know how to stop it from auto-updating were I to finally manage to download and install it.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? I'm using the latest rc build of Windows 10 and 050 won't stay up for more than 10 minutes at most.

Comment: @tjgienger No, actually, I'm using Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, this is perhaps not the most ideal solution (not to mention unsupported), but you may try the following.

Assuming you've updated Visual Studio Code forthrough the embeddeda auto-updater:

1. On Windows, start by navigating to `%APPDATA%` in Explorer
2. Next, browse to: Local\Code

Depending on your machine config, chances are you'll find both the latest and previous assemblies in the app-xxxx subfolders.

[image: Visual Studio Code - previous versions]

Note that the version numbers do not match the assembly versions of VSCode but have another purpose. You can verify which version it is per app-xxx folder by **rightlicking on the Code.exe file**, selecting properties and looking at the Details tab for the Product version info.

**Edit**: You can simply execute the older Code.exe version and leave the rest intact. There is no need to delete anything.

[image]

Currently, the older versions are still available for download at some places online, but this isn't a supported scenario. Best chances are joining the *Insider Updates* where you do have this option. It wouldn't hurt to [make a feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/) out of this, though.

Comment: I think you forgot to actually write out that you are supposed to execute the matching .exe file, not delete the other folder like I was about to do before I realized what you meant!

Comment: Does anyone have the original installation files for 030? I had uninstalled and reinstalled when I started having these issues. Now I no longer have the older versions. Shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

From [Visual Studio Code FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq):

You can install a previous release of VS Code by uninstalling your current version and then installing the download provided at the top of a specific release page under [Updates](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/).

Note: The link you want is in the body of the page--it is not the download link in the nav-bar.

Answer (score -1):

Version 0.5.0 is very stable for me on Windows 8.1. So maybe you should consider whether something else is wrong?

Comment: No idea how. 0.3.0 worked fine and 0.5.0 had no interesting updates for me so I'm fine this way.